# Good introductory book for matrix calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, multivariable-calculus

Hi I am an electronics graduate and working on image processing for the past one year...I have a basic exposure to linear algebra(thanks to Gilbert Strang..!!!). Now I am facing problems with matrix calculus and its notation because many image processing algorithms are using matrix and vector calculus...please refer me some introductory book for matrix calculus or linear algebra books containing calculus concepts...just out of curosity...will a multivariate calculus book serve the introductions i am looking for?? if yes...do suggest be one...

Comment: A similar question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/reference-for-matrix-calculus?rq=1).

Comment: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/matrix/ 
It is not a book. It is an excellent introductory reference written by Minka that deals with matrix calculus in the context of machine learning and optimization, which includes topics such as inference techniques in image processing.